# Question On Solutions for a Specific Congruence $ax \equiv 1 \pmod p$ when $p$ is prime and $p \not\mid a$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I have been working through exercises within a book on polynomials. Part (f.) of a particular exercise asks the following :

Show that, if $p$ is a prime, and $a$ is not a multiple of $p$, then there is exactly one value of $x$ satisfying :
\begin{equation}
a x \equiv 1  \pmod p \text{ and } 1 \leq x \leq p - 1
\end{equation}

In part (d.) of the exercise the reader is asked to show that when :
\begin{equation}
ax \equiv b \pmod m
\end{equation}
we have :
\begin{equation}
g = \text{gcd}(a,m) \text{ and } g \mid b \Rightarrow ax \equiv b \pmod m \text{ has a solution}
\end{equation}
Here $c|d$ means $d$ is divisible by $c$. In the above equations $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is considered a solution.

Based on the result from part (d.) I can deduce that for $g = \text{gcd}(a,p)$ :
\begin{equation}
g \mid 1 \Rightarrow ax \equiv 1 \pmod p \text{ has a solution }
\end{equation}
So we know :
\begin{align}
p \text{ is prime and } p \not\mid a & \Rightarrow g = \text{gcd}(a,p) = 1 \\\\
                                   & \Rightarrow g \mid 1                   \\\\
                                   & \Rightarrow ax \equiv 1 \pmod p \text{ has a solution } \; \checkmark
\end{align}
So that a solution exists. The question is how can I show that there is a single solution and that :
\begin{equation}
x \in \{1,...,p-1\}
\end{equation}
Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: If $ax_1\equiv ax_2\pmod p$ then $p\,|\,a(x_1-x_2)$.  Since $p\nmid a$ we must have $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod p$.

Comment: so there are lots of solutions, but only one is in $\{1,...,p-1\}$